How to recive and sent order from outer device in MS ACCESS
I need to create a function within the MS Access application, which will instantly accept an order from the barrier for the passage of people, through the network (by reading the bar code from the card, which is printed through that database, and of course the code is recorded in the table of the base), and then after passing through the conditional algorithm, send back the answer 1 or 0 (pass, or no pass)? Is that possible in MS Access? Thank you.
Help, maybe a short example...
